# Process of securing a hacked EOS account?

Tags: active-key, owner-key, stake, hacked-account, unstake

I've managed to setup an EOS account and have changed my Owner key to something else. Now my owner and active keys are different.

From my what I know so far. I should stake my EOS balance if I'm not doing anything with it as this prevents someone from sending out my EOS if it does get hacked.

I then setup an alert service at: https://eosauthority.com/alerts

Now my question is lets say I do know I got hacked. What do I do now?

As I never did this, do I load my **OWNER** private key into a new wallet and then **change** the active key to something else to prevent the hacker from doing anything? Or is there another step I do not know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I never did this, do I load my OWNER private key into a new wallet and then change the active key to something else to prevent the hacker from doing anything?

Yes.

> Or is there another step I do not know about?

If you want to or if you believe that the wallet you used may be insecure, you can generate new key(s) for the owner and reset your `owner` authority to those key pairs whose secret keys have never been in a wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my basic incident response plan if an EOS account I control is hacked:

1. Regain control of the hacked account by changing the owner/active key pairs
2. Identify all transactions if any that were done without my real authorization but with my active or previous owner key pairs
3. Contact block producers on the telegram channel @EOSProsto and get further assistance
4. Possibly involve ECAF and [file a claim](https://eoscorearbitration.io/file-a-claim/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful tutorial for changing active keys and permissions https://medium.com/eos-new-york/managing-your-eos-owner-active-permissions-c76bdaf24e6b